# Selenium Builder to create a data driven UI Automation Framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-builder

I recently came across Selenium Builder and found it very useful as it gives ability to record a test and export the script in multiple languages.
I am analysing for using it to create a UI Automation Framework. Anyone having any experience / suggestion on this.

I am thinking to implement following design:

```
1. Record a Test with Sel Builder. 
2. Export as java 
3. Customise the script where needed (e.g. getting current date, Referring values from previous steps etc. )
4. Execute and Baseline Tests.
```

Now the challenge will be how to make it data-driven. I can write a script to parse the code and put it into excel files (action and data). This will give a readymade data file for QA team to work on. 
And again add some more features/script for reports creation.

Will this be a good design and solution.

Comment: My thought process here is to speed up the process of TestData creation and Script creation.
Ofcourse to make it data-driven this will require some more coding and features.
I will also create a POC and check this.

Any suggestion / feedback / better ideas on this